# What is the difference Between Primitive array and Array of Reference .

Tags: java, arrays

I read in net and Found reference array store references. References in sense the array is going to store memory address of variables i Guess if i am not mistaken. If that's the Case why i don't see the memory address when i loop through string array as Below.

```
  String[] arrNames = new String[3];
  arrNames[0]       = "John";
  arrNames[1]       = "Mac";
  arrNames[2]       = "Alex";
```

Now  as per the definition the arrNames array is going to store References at arrNames[0],arrNames[1], arrNames[2]. Which means memory address which is going to point to Names i.eJohn, Max and Alex.

If it is Primitive array its directly going to store the values like below.

```
 int[] Num = new int[3];
 Num[0]    = 1;
 Num[1]    = 2;
 Num[2]    = 3;
```

The Num[0] is directly going to hold Numbers 1 instead of address which points to number.

Please correct me if i misunderstood it.

Comment: It's the same as the difference between a primitive variable and an object variable, except that there are more of them. Java hides addresses from you deliberately.

Comment: So a object variable is going to store memory address right

Comment: No, an object variable stores a "reference" to the object, which is an abstract thing that Java really doesn't want to you worry about. At a low level, yes it's basically a pointer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1

Answer (score 1):

In java there is no primitive array. Even though we had the primitive values in an array, then the array itself considered as array object.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive arrays and Reference arrays are exactly similar object.

Moreover, default values also applied with a primitive array:

```
int[] myPrimitiveArray = new int[1];

assertTrue(myPrimitiveArray[0], 0)     //passed since 0 by default in each cell
```

Same as:

```
Integer[] myReferenceArray = new Integer[1];

assertTrue(myPrimitiveArray[0], 0)     //passed since 0 by default in each cell
```